# Why does my program loop without receiving any new input?

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to make is so that my program will start over once the answer is given.  It just won't function again once I run it once.  I want to make it functional to where the user doesn't have to start the program up again.  Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()
{
    float firstnum, secondnum, answer;
    char function;

    printf("\nHello and welcome to my calculator!\n");                                             //Intro

    start:                                                                                         //Area to loop to when program completes

    printf("\nPlease input the function you would like to use.  These include +, -, *, /.\n");     //Asking for function input

    scanf("%c", &function);                                                                        //Receiving Function Input

    printf("\nNow please input the two variables.\n");                                             //Asking for variables

    scanf("%f", &firstnum);

    scanf("%f", &secondnum);                                                                       //Receiving Input for Variables

    if (function == '+')                                                                           //Doing calculation
    {
            answer = firstnum+secondnum;
    }
    else if (function == '-')
    {
    answer = firstnum-secondnum;
    }
    else if (function == '*')
    {
    answer = firstnum*secondnum;
    }
    else if (function == '/')
    {
    answer = firstnum/secondnum;
    }
    else
    {
            printf("Sorry that was an incorrect function.  The correct inputs are +, -, *, /.");       //If they don't follow the directions
    }

    printf("Your answer is %f \n", answer);                                                        //Answer

    goto start;                                                                                    //Loop

return 0;
```

}

Comment: bugger...... whats your question ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why you use loops. (And try not to use goto for this).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main() {

    float firstnum, secondnum, answer;
    char function, buffer[2];

    while(1) {      

        printf("\nHello and welcome to my calculator!\n");                                             

        printf("\nPlease input the function you would like to use.  These include +, -, *, /.\n");     
        scanf("%s", &buffer);   
        function = buffer[0];
        printf("\nNow please input the two variables.\n");  
        scanf("%f", &firstnum);
        scanf("%f", &secondnum);
        if (function == '+') answer = firstnum+secondnum;
        else if (function == '-') answer = firstnum-secondnum;
        else if (function == '*') answer = firstnum*secondnum;
        else if (function == '/') answer = firstnum/secondnum;
        else printf("Sorry that was an incorrect function.  The correct inputs are +, -, *, /.");    

        printf("Your answer is %f \n", answer);                                                               
        } 

     return 0;
     }
```

This should go in an infinite loop, so use an input from the user to `break;` the loop to exit the program

---

Note : I have replaced the scanf %c with %s indicating an input of a string & used a buffer.

```
 scanf("%s",&buffer); function = buffer[0];
```

*(Updated as per discussion in comments)*

Comment: Good advice to not use goto to control flow .... but your program still has the same bug. see @luser droog's answer.

Comment: How is `scanf("%d", &function)` going to interpret '/'? or '*'?

Comment: @luserdroog Thanks for pointing out. Failed to notice OP used characters like '/' as the input...

Comment: scanf("%d", &function); scanf expects &function to be an int ptr. You're suggesting to use a char ptr. That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ooooh. I like it now! But it needs room for the '\0'.

Comment: The input is expected to be a single char. Why not use %*[ \n] to discard whitespace followed by %c?

Comment: @modifia That's worth putting in an answer.

Comment: @loxxy Yeah, you're tearing into unallocated space. It writes a zero on the neighbor's fence, figuratively.

Comment: ... or do { puts("Enter an operator"); function = getchar(); } while (strchr("+-/*", function) == NULL);

Comment: @ luserdroog  Yea it does.
@modifiablelvalue You should collate all your comments into an answer.

Comment: @loxxy would do, but writing anything on an ipod is difficult.

Comment: Can anyone post another answer?  The one answer doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please make sure you click green tick mark, next to any answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 2):

It's the [enter] key. Your first `scanf` is reading the enter key you pressed to terminate the previous iteration.

So you need to add another `scanf("%c", &function);` or `getchar();` just before the `goto` to eat the newline.

When reading in numbers, `scanf` will eat any initial whitespace; but when reading characters, it won't. It gives you the very next byte in the stream.

---

<del>A better way, perhaps, would be to tell `scanf` where to expect all the newlines. This way you don't need that *weird* mystery line that doesn't appear to do anything but isn't commented (!); because that's gonna cause problems when you play with this code again months from now.</del>

```
//scanf("%c\n", &function); /* read a character followed by newline DOESN'T WORK */
...
//scanf("%f\n", &secondnum); /* read a number followed by newline DOESN'T WORK */
```

<del>This way, *trailing* newlines are consumed. Which is, I think, the more intuitive behavior (from the User side).</del>
 Nope. Doesn't work. Wish it did, cause I'd look less foolish.

---

I'm not upset by the `goto`. It's nice to see an old friend. This is an appropriate use of it if ever there was one. It is exactly equivalent to the `while` form. So you should certainly be aware that *most people* will prefer to see `while(1)` because it tells you more about what's going on than `label:`. But for an infinite loop in a function smaller than a screen, why not? Have fun. No baby seals will be harmed. :)

Comment: I don't really understand.  The code still just skips the input of function doesn't read the input of the numbers.  Also, if i do what you said it won't read the input when i press enter.  I am sorry I am a total noob at this.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show us exactly what it looks like now?

Comment: My second suggestion was a little off. It's the secondnum that's followed by newline, right? So it's *that one* that needs the `\n` in the format string.

Comment: @MattPrice I'm sorry. You're right. My second suggestion was totally wrong. The first one works.

Answer (score 0):

One "best practise" regarding scanf is to check it's return value. In regards to the return value of scanf, I suggest reading [this scanf manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html) carefully and answering the following questions:

1. int x = scanf("%d", &foo); What do you suppose x will be if I enter "fubar\n" as input?
2. Where do you suppose the 'f' from "fubar\n" will go?
3. If it remains in stdin, would you expect a second scanf("%d", &foo); to be successful?
4. int x = scanf("%d", &foo); What do you suppose x will be if I run this code on Windows and press CTRL+Z to send EOF to stdin?
5. Would it be safe to use foo if x is less than 1? Why not?
6. int x = scanf("%d %d", &foo, &bar); What would you expect x to be if I enter "123 456\n" as input?
7. Do you suppose the '\n' will still be on stdin? What value would char_variable hold following scanf("%c", &char_variable);?

EOF can be sent through stdin in Windows by CTRL+Z, and in Linux and friends by CTRL+D, in addition to using pipes and redirection to redirect input from other programs and files.

By using code like `int function; for (function = getchar(); function >= 0 && isspace(function); function = getchar()); assert(function >= 0);` or `char function; assert(scanf("%*[ \n]%c", &function) == 1);` you can discard leading whitespace before assigning to function.