# C - scanf waits until all parts in format can be evaluated

Tags: c, scanf

I don't have a lot of time, and a lot of the stuff about `stdin` just raises a lot more questions than it answers at this stage. I was hoping to test for multiple types of commands passed with mutliple instances of `scanf`.

If I do this:

```
char inputChar;
char inputChars[15] = { NULL };
int inputInt;
double inputDec;

if(scanf("%c %d %lf",&inputChar,&inputInt,&inputDec) == 3) {
    ...
}
else if(scanf("%c %d %s",&inputChar,&inputInt,&inputChars) == 3) {
    ...
}
else if(scanf("%c %d",&inputChar,&inputInt) == 2) {
    ...
}
else if(scanf("%c",&inputChar) == 1) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

And then type a single character and hit Enter, the console waits until I enter another value before assessing whether or not there's a match.

**Update**

This seems to work fine, except that it expects your input to the *perfect* whenever it's used. If a user types `aa` then changes it to `a 10` before hitting Enter, it matches the 4th evaluation. It's wrong for two reasons:

1. Because it *should* match the 3rd if it's capturing input correctly; and
2. Because if it *doesn't*, `aa` should be filtered into the 5th evaluation.

Revised code:

```
char input[50] = { NULL };

char inputChar = NULL;
char inputChars[15] = { NULL };
int inputInt;
double inputDec;

printf("Input String:\n>");

fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);

if(sscanf(input,"%c%d %lf",&inputChar,&inputInt,&inputDec) == 3) { }
else if(sscanf(input,"%c%d%s",&inputChar,&inputInt,&inputChars) == 3) { }
else if(sscanf(input,"%c%d",&inputChar,&inputInt) == 2) { }
else if(sscanf(input,"%c",&inputChar) == 1) { }
else { }
```

Doing something like this shows that backspace is not being filtered out:

```
for(int i=0;i<50;i++) {
    if(input[i] == (char) 10) { break; }
    printf("\n%c %d",(char) input[i],(int) input[i]);
}
```

So it appears `fgets` is out of the picture.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? The behavior you are observing is what is supposed to happen.

Comment: Well, yes. Your first `scanf` call says to read any character (`"%c"`), then 0 or more whitespace characters (`" "`). Newline counts as whitespace.

Comment: It seems inconsistent to me that it's possible for one use of `scanf` to poison subsequent uses (thereby necessitating `_flushall`), and yet something like this requires that I go out of my way to make it do what I would otherwise want it not to do.

Comment: @DissidentRage What is `_flushall`?

Comment: Also I tried replacing the whitespace with `[^\n]` and it had no effect whatsoever.

Comment: @melpomene - `_flushall` clears the input buffer

Comment: @DissidentRage `%d`, `%lf`, and `%s` all skip whitespace. The spaces in your format strings are redundant. `scanf` is simply not designed for line-based input.

Comment: @DissidentRage: There is no _flushall in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best way to go about it but it works.

Using the `iostream` library run `getline(std::cin,input);` to capture input to `std::string input` then use `sscanf` however many times on `input.c_str()`.

Answer (score 2):

The statements are executed in order. So it's the first `scanf` call that waits for more input. If the input doesn't match the first call, then the next `scanf` call will start all over, waiting for input. And so on.

Instead you should use `fgets` to read the whole line, and then use `sscanf` on the line.

Comment: More specifically, use `sscanf` a few times.

Comment: It seems pretty easy to get a false reaction to one of the format checks. I were using two instances of `sscanf` with `"%c%d"` and `"%c"` then typed `aa`, then changed the value to `a 10` before hitting Enter, it would evaluate as matching the second format and not the first.

Answer (score 1):

Please explain what "clears the input buffer" means. Do you mean _flushall erases my keystrokes before they occur? How could it do this? Perhaps you mean that you've already read the data that you need from the line, and you don't care about the rest of the line. In that case, I assume you wish to "read and discard all characters up to and including the next newline". I have a portable mechanism to do that:

```
for (int c = getchar(); c >= 0 && c != '\n'; c = getchar());
```

You may also wish to read [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993841/why-does-my-program-loop-without-receiving-any-new-input/14994382#14994382).

*edit*: It has just occured to me that the behaviour you desire might be expressed as follows:

```
char inputChar;
char inputChars[15] = { NULL };
int inputInt;
double inputDec;
int x = scanf("%c%d", &inputChar, &inputInt);

if (x == 2 && scanf("%lf",&inputDec) == 1) {
    ...
}
else if (x == 2 && scanf("%14s", inputChars) == 1) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I've looked it up and it appears that `_flushall` is native to Visual Studio, so it looks like it's not a good idea to continue using it.

Comment: An alternative is `%*[^\n]%*c` at the end of your format strings, like so: `if(scanf("%c %d %lf%*[^\n]%*c",&inputChar,&inputInt,&inputDec) == 3) { /* ... */ } ...`. `%*[^\n]` consumes and discards all characters up to a '\n', and `%*c` consumes and discards that '\n'.

Comment: Tried that. It was ineffectual.

Comment: I've attempted to use this by adding the characters to a character array then introducing the character array size as another limiter. It works well but it doesn't capture the first character.